# MySQL Workbench cambiar nombre al Schema

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy intentando exportar/migrar una BD de un servidor a otro, tengo las 2 conexiones en `Workbench` y el problema es que las bases tienen nombres diferentes, yo quiero coger la base a exportar llamémosla **prueba** y quiero exportarla a **prueba1** y **prueba2**.

Las exportaciones se crean con el Schema prueba entonces no la puedo exportar a esas otras 2... ¿alguien sabe cómo cambiar el nombre?

Una solución sería cambiar uno a uno los inserts... un palo.

Otra sería en vez de migrar, exportar pero te exporta un .sql por tabla por lo que es un palo cuando tienes muchas tablas...

¿Alguna otra idea?

Comment: Disculpa la pregunta, pero, ¿este proceso que haces te genera algún error o buscas otra forma de solucionar este proceso? Si tienes errores, [edit] tu pregunta añadiendo la descripción del error.

Comment: no es ningún error, busco una manera sencilla de cambiar el nombre del schema mediante MySQL Workbench

Comment: Porque no importas la bd en fichero sql.
Lo abres con el editor de texto.
Le cambias las dos referencias del nombre de la base de datos.
Guardas el fichero en sql.
Y lo lanzas como un script de SQL.
Mas sencillo, imposible. Slds

Comment: Depende de la versión que uses. QUé versión del workbench tienes?

Answer (score 1):

Lo más fácil es que abras el fichero exportado y le cambies el nombre al esquema. A mi me pasó lo mismo y es lo más rápido.

Comment: Sí, me parece a mí que es lo que me va a tocar hacer... pero me parece muy raro que algo tan simple como eso no sea posible...

Answer (score 1):

Si usas **MySQL 5.1.7** puedes usar el comando:

```
RENAME db1 TO db2;
```

*Esta característica fue considerada peligrosa por lo que fue removida de MySQL 5.1.23*

Otra alternativa que puedes intentar es exportar un dump, crear otra base datos e importar el dump, aquí los pasos:

```
mysql> mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -p db1 > dump.sql
mysql> create database db2;
mysql> mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p db2 < dump.sql
```

Para borrar la db1 usa el siguiente comando:

```
mysql> drop database db1;
```

Comment: sólo tengo acceso mediante MySQL Workbench

Comment: Quizas esto te sirva: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545634/how-do-i-rename-a-mysql-schema

Comment: pero si tienes el cliente tienes acceso a la consola usas windows o linux?

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que te refieres a como hacerlo gráficamente con la herramienta `MySQL WorkBench`, en ese caso solo has doble-click sobre el nombre de la base de datos y te desplegara un panel de configuración donde podrás editar el nombre, codificación de carácter y demás.

[image: Renombrar base de datos]

Answer (score 0):

Según la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html), debería ser posible. Algunas consideraciones:

- Hay que buscar que el export no tenga el schema indicado. Habría que probar desmarcando la opción de incluír el CREATE SCHEMA
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- En el export, Advanced options, probar desmarcando la opción que añade todos los CREATE options que añade MySQL
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Ten en cuenta la nota en el wizard de importar. Si el export viene con el schema, no es posible hacerle override desde este wizard.

[image: nota en el wizard de import]